# How to create a two way table for a panel data set?

Tags: r, panel

I have the following data set in **R**:

```
Country     Year       Population
   A        2000         1,000
   A        2001         1,100
   A        2002         1,200
   B        2000         1,150
   B        2001       
   B        2003         1,400
   C        2000       
   C        2001         1,000
   C        2003         1,100
```

Where the empty spaces represent missing values. I am trying to create a two way table with the years of available data for the population column. Something like this:

```
Country  2000  2001  2002
   A       1     1     1
   B       1     0     1
   C       0     1     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dcast` to convert your data into wide format. Also, you can use `spread` from dplyr.

**Method 1:**

```
library(data.table)
dcast(df[!is.na(df$Population),], formula = Country ~ Year, fun.aggregate = length)

print(df)
  Country 2000 2001 2002 2003
1       A    1    1    1    0
2       B    1    0    0    1
3       C    0    1    0    1
```

**Method 2:**

```
df %>% 
    mutate(row_id = if_else(is.na(Population),0,1)) %>% 
    select(-Population) %>% 
    spread(Year, row_id,fill=0)

  Country 2000 2001 2002 2003
1       A    1    1    1    0
2       B    1    0    0    1
3       C    0    1    0    1
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i needed.